# ¿Cómo controlar la cantidad de decimales en un input?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, html5, input

Tengo un campo tipo number en mi tabla de longitud (12,3) es decir, que mi aplicación solo debería dejarme ingresar hasta 9 dígitos delante del dígito separador y hasta 3 después de este.

¿Alguien sabe cómo construir esta máscara en mi input en HTML o en JavaScript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes utilizar regex para verificar la máscara.

```js
const input = document.querySelector("#myInput")

input.onkeydown = (e)=>{

    const currentValue = input.value;
 
    const regex = /^\d{0,9}(\.\d{1,3})?$/

    setTimeout(function(){
      const newValue = input.value

      if(!regex.test(newValue))
        input.value = currentValue; 
    }, 0); 

}
```

```html
 <input id="myInput" type="number">
```

Comment: no funciona, da error al añadir cualquier decimal (ej. 1.1) y permite números enteros mayores de nueve cifras si sigues escribiendo en el input.

Comment: No entiendo, el script te bloquea y lo máximo que puedes escribir es:
999999999.999

Comment: escribe 1.1 por ejemplo y clicka fuera, da error. Y me acaba de dejar escribir 999999999999999999999999999999 sin dar error. Estoy en Firefox.

Comment: Ya verifiqué con Firefox y sí. está muy raro, no sé si sea incompatibilidad de stackoverflow o de Firefox. Podrías verificar con chrome?. También, podrías copiar eso en tu editor de código y abrirlo con Firefox?. Tal vez el problema sea la función de ejecutar en la página con el navegador. En chrome funciona bien.

Comment: He hecho un fidlle https://jsfiddle.net/a9e5dtz2/ con tu código, funciona en Chrome y efectivamente falla en Firefox

Comment: Desconozco la razón. Tal vez Firefox no soporta ese Regex.

Answer (score 1):

Una forma sencilla es restringir los valores mínimo y máximo en el input, y para que tenga hasta 3 decimales se define con `step`. Valores que no cumplan estos criterios darán error en el `input`.

Este sería un ejemplo:

```html
<input type="number" step="0.001" min="0" max="999999999.999">
```

Comment: pues no funciona correctamente si agregas 9999.9999 no envia error

Comment: @MiguelZarate si pones 9999.9999 y a continuación clickas fuera veras que el campo marca error (se bordea en rojo) porque no pasa la validación html